# Получить get в django python, отфильтрованный в models

Tags: python, django

можно ли получить результат get, причем вызывая метод в модели вызываемого класса?
то есть надо просто вернуть запись, но без некоторых полей

**view**

```
cls = Class.objects.get(related_uuid='xxx')
```

и надо чтобы при выводе через цикл cls, выводило только конкретные поля. в самом views это указывать нельзя, только в models. как это реализовать?

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)    
    related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)
```

Comment: не очень понятна суть, но в классе модели можно определять и переопределять функции через "def".  Направление, что погуглить "толстые модели"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, то что вы ищете будет выглядеть так

**models**

```
class Order(models.Model):
  device = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  serial = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)    
  related_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True)
  
  def get_device(self):
    return self.device
```

ну, вызов будет такой

```
cls = Order.objects.get(serial=serial) # пример выборки по данному полю
device = cls.get_device()
```

И еще один момент, лучше имена классов давать в единственном числе

```
class Order(models.Model)....
```

Comment: спасибо большое! а как вернуть в return сразу несколько переменных? через dict лучше?

Comment: создайте dict в теле функции `get_device()`, определите все что хотите забрать, поместите в dict, верните dict